# Problemas con la memoria al subir un archivo por input tipo file

Tags: php, cakephp

Al subir un archivo por un input tipo file, el archivo es un tipo excel, en el cual se debe llenar una tabla con diferentes datos, cuando se sube al servidor me da el siguiente error

> PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8978294 bytes exceeds the limit
>   of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Cambie los valores de

```
post-max-size (change 8M to 800M).
upload-max-filesize (change 2M to 2000M).
```

PD: use varios valores y ninguno funciono.

cuando lo hice me apareció otro error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 64 bytes)

Formulario en cakePHP:

```
<div class="btn boton btn-default btn-file col-md-7" style="padding-bottom: 4%;">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create(
               'Ordenmateriale',
                array(
                    'id' => 'formulario',
                    'class' => 'boton',
                    'type' => 'file'
                )
            );
        ?>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input(
                'archivo',
                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'class' => 'boton',
                    'label'=>'  <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> <br>Migrar Datos :'
                )
            );
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 2%;">
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->submit(
                'Adjuntar Archivo',
                array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary boton col-md-3 ',
                    'title' => 'Click Aqui para Adjuntar',
                    'onclick' => 'return validar();'
                )
            );
            echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, debes aumentar el tamaño de la variable `upload_max_filesize = 1000M;` `post_max_size = 1000M;` y `memory_limit = 512M` ***o superior*** en el archivo php.ini y luego reiniciar Apache (siempre, al realizar un cambio de configuración debes reiniciarlo).

Comment: Yo creo que no tengo claro todo el proceso, incluso me siento en un ambiente de pura improvisan, ¿tienes algún ejemplo? .  Te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: @reder82 si tienes un servidor Xampp o Wampp, buscas el archivo `php.ini`. En Xampp la ruta es `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` y lo abres con un editor de texto. Ya dentro, buscas las variables que te mencioné y le asignas los valores. Luego entras en Xampp Control Panel y buscas el botón que dice **Stop** frente a los módulos de Apache y MySQL. Cuando estén detenidos, pulsas el botón **Start** de los mismos servicios. https://imgur.com/a/72Q3ngP

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar me gustaría ver el formulario desde donde cargas tu archivo pues debes considerar el `name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value=`

Por otro lado el código **PHP** debe validar lo enviado por el formulario. Y el primer mensaje es solo una alerta que puedes validar con `$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['error']`

Cuánto pesa tu archivo Excel? y cómo piensas procesarlo para llenar tus tablas?
Tienes claro todo el proceso?

Comment: se reinicia apagando y volviendo a prender los servidores?

Comment: Supongo que te refieres al servidor Apache, sí solo lo reinicias y listo.